# Will spring HandlerInterceptor work for Jax-RS rest controller inside spring boot application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jersey, jax-rs

I have a conbination of spring boot plus Java-RS rest controller. I am trying to figure out if spring HandlerInterceptor would work for Jax-rs rest controller?

Comment: First response no. Second response it depends if it is behind the DispatcherServlet or not (generally it is not, so no it will not work).

Comment: Is there any problem to put the Jax-RS behind dispatcher servlet ? Does not look to me as complicated?

Comment: It depends how one uses jax-rs, default is using a filter (IIRC) and that is quite impossible to put behind a servlet.

Comment: You will need to use a ContainerRequestFilter. You can inject the HttpServletRequest into it. And if you need the Method, you can inject [ResourceInfo](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/ResourceInfo.html). If you need to handle something post-request processing, you can use a ContainerResponseFilter.